# quadratic featurizer: preprocessing with fit_transform

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

the following example is written in Python and is taken from the book [Mastering Machine Learning](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/mastering-machine-learning-scikit-learn).

Overview of the task:

- training data is stored in column vectors *X_train* (features) and *y_train* (response variables)
- data for testing purposes is respectively stored in *X_test* and *y_test*
- now fit a model to the training data using polynomial regression (in this case quadratic)

The author's approach (imports and data initialization excluded):

```
quad_featurizer = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_train_quad = quad_featurizer.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_quad = quad_featurizer.transform(X_test)

regressor_quad = LinearRegression()
regressor_quad.fit(X_train_quad, y_train)
```

The author didn't comment the code or tells anything more about the methods used. Since the scikit-learn API couldn't give me a satisfying answer either, I'd like to ask you.

**Why would I use *fit_transform* and not just *transform* for preprocessing the training data?** I mean the actual fitting is done with the *regressor_quad* object, so *fit_transform* is redundant, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those featurizers of scikit must be adjusted to your specific dataset and only afterwards can transform it to new feature vectors. `fit()` performs that adjustment. Therefore you need to first call `fit()` and then `transform()`, or both at the same time via `fit_transform()`.

In your example `PolynomialFeatures` is used to project your training data into a new higher-dimensional space. So a vector `(3, 6)` would become `(1, 3, 6, 3*3, 3*6, 6*6)`. In `fit()` `PolynomialFeatures` learns the size of your training vectors and in `transform()` it creates new training vectors from the old ones. So `X_train_quad` is a new matrix with a shape that is different from `X_train`. Afterwards the same is done with `X_test` but then `PolynomialFeatures` knows already the sizes of your vectors so it doesn't have to be `fit()` again. `LinearRegression` is then trained on your new training data (`X_train_quad`) via its `fit()` method, which is completely separated from `PolynomialFeatures` and therefore its `fit()` doesn't really have anything to do with `fit()` of `PolynomialFeatures`.

Comment: Thank you a lot! My misconception was in thinking that PolynomialFeatures.fit() is equal to LinearRegression.fit().